# Can you do analysis on the set of shapes in the plane?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am wondering if it possible to consider a set of well behaved sets in the plane (say convex, closed, etc. you decide), define a metric on them, and do analysis;
we can consider functions from the shapes to $R$, and hope to define what continuity, diffrentiablitiy is, so that we are able to find maximums and minimums of functions over sets of shapes. Maybe this is too general, and we can do only things if we define $f:R^2 \to R$, and consider only functions that derive from those somehow (Such as the integral over the shape).

I don't have much self progress I'm afraid.

Comment: Look up "Gromov-Hausdorff metric."

Comment: Yes. Gromov defines a distance between any given compact metric spaces. Any compact set in Euclidean space is itself a compact space in particular.

Comment: Look at integral geometry and the book by Santalo. This considers sets of objects which are invariant under a group action (e.g. the set of straight lines in the plane is invariant under affine transformations) and have a natural measure on them derived from the haar measure of the group.

Comment: There is the Hausdorff metric